# Adding a drop down field to user registration

Tags: entities, 8

We are using Drupal 8 for one of our new project and we need to add a country dropdown to the user registration form. I see that we can add a select box through Manage fields section, but how do I make it configurable?

I mean I want to show the values in the select box from a configurable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've found where you can add user fields (under **Administration >> Configuration >> People >> Account settings**). Once you've clicked the **+ Add Field** button, you can select *List (text)*, add your Label, and click the **Save and Continue** button to configure the options you can add to your country select list.

Here is where you add your list of items. The **Allowed values list** text field is where you can add your selectable items. You can add each country you want, once per line. Once finished, you can click the **Save field settings** to continue to the final configuration page.

Customize the remaining settings and click the **Save setting** button to finish adding the country select box for your user account.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for thsi and it is working. However is there a way to fetch this values from a database table?

Comment: Are you wanting to fetch the values of the options or the value selected during user registration?